# Sending emails to users based on their language preference

Tags: wordpress

Basically, I need to allow my users to create a language in their profile settings. Me, as an admin, needs to be able to send emails to my users depending on what language they choose.

e.g. spanish users get emails in spanish, english users get emails in english

I know how to add custom preferences to a user's profile (perhaps someone could refer me to a plugin that facilitates this process?), but I don't know how to change a user's user-group based on what language they've chosen.

Because I have a plugin that allows you to send emails to specific user groups.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can help me achieve this? Perhaps someone knows of a better way for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quickest way is to add a select field on the user's profile, where the user can pick its language.

To do that, you can either add fields tweaking this code and adding it to your functions file:
http://bavotasan.com/2009/adding-extra-fields-to-the-wordpress-user-profile/

Or through this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Then to get a user specific field, use this function:

```
<?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);  ?>
```